# Is it possible to call an external class from inside a Laravel 8 migration?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-8

I have created a class (`SomeClass`) and it has a method (`SomeMethod`). `SomeClass::SomeMethod` retrieves data from a third party.

In one of my migrations, I would like to call `SomeClass::SomeMethod` in the `up()` function so that I automatically populate the fresh table with that data after I have done a migration.

Is this possible?

I have looked a bit and the closest example I can find is this:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
    '--class' => 'SomeClass::SomeMethod',
]);
```

But I'm using an existing class instead of a seeder because it's real data, not faked or fixed data.

Comment: seeders are not only for fake data! (use model factory for fake data). create a seeder class and call ``SomeClass::SomeMethod`` inside that

Comment: a seeder would be better as mentioned and this is all PHP so yea you can call a method on any class

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this in the database migration. Create a seeder instead and get the data within the `run` method.

```
php artisan make:seeder YourTableSeeder
```

Depending on the format of the data that `SomeClass::SomeMethod` gets you, you may have to loop over it differently.

```php
use Path\To\SomeClass;

public function run()
{
    $data = SomeClass::SomeMethod();

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        Model::create($row);

        // or use the DB facade to insert if you're not using a model.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran into an issue with using my SomeClass::SomeMethod here, so I used DB::statement to copy data from a backup table and it works perfectly.